# activeadmin menu links fail when deployed into namespace other than root?

Tags: deployment, menu, routes, activeadmin

Somewhat new to active admin (4-5 internal apps).  I've found it to be straightforward and flexible.

However, when I deploy an app to a context other than root, the menus fail.

For example given a domain, 'Rate' the menu generates a link to '/admin/rates'.  No problems, all works as expected.  However, if I deploy to context '/xyz' the menu still generates a link  of '/admin/rates' instead of the '/xyz/admin/rates' expected.

Is there a configuration step I might have missed?

Thanks

Edit...

I'm deploying on torquebox

Tried surrounding in a scope, made me more confused.  ie 
/xyz/xyz/admin/rates

```
scope :path => '/xyz' do
 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In your project directory look for app/admin/rates.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Rate do
    menu :url => "/app/admin/rates" 
end
```

This will change the URL that the menu item links to only. Without affecting the routing in rails.